# Geo Chart not showing region of Pakistan, in googleViz package

Tags: r, csv, google-visualization

I have a data of "population" Pakistan of its four provinces(1. KPK, 2. Punjab, 3. Sindh, 4. Baluchistan and 5. Islamabad () and wanted to show it on Geo chart like the given

```
    p.name population
1          KPK       3615
2       Punjab       5348
3        Sindh       5500
4 Baloachistan       4500
5    Islamabad       2500

G <- gvisGeoChart(pop, "state.name", "population",
                          options=list(region="Pakistan", 
                                       resolution="provinces",
                                       width=600, height=400))
```

But showing the alert `Requested map does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

try using [*an uppercase ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code*](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format)

```
options=list(region="PK",
```